# Gmail adds multiple SPF records

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf, gmail, txt-record

When I connected my domain to gmail, it added two records to my DNS:

```
TXT
@
v=spf1 include:dc-aa8e722993._spfm.mydomainhere.com ~all


TXT
dc-aa8e722993._spfm
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

But everything I see online about setting up SPF properly says to include just one record:

```
TXT
@
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Should I just change the name on the second record to be @? Or should I let them be? What is the meaning of the two records that gmail created?

Comment: I cannot find where the `dc-aa8e722993._spfm` comes from. It is copy-pasted on several forums, but it is not part of any standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why Google would do this, but what you have is one arbitrary TXT record (the second one) which includes the Google SPF stack, and an actual SPF record which includes the second one. I suspect that the intent is to separate your own SPF record - in case you have another mail server somewhere - and Google's, in case they have to change it. I wouldn't change it, as written it will work just fine, and I have to assume there is some method in Google's madness. Perhaps it's meant to simplfy updates: if the only thing in the record Google needs to change is their own stack, it is simpler to code the change.